# Can't change span content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
// create text <span>
var text = document.createTextNode("Some content I want to replace... ");
var textspan = document.createElement("span");
textspan.id = "text" + counter;
textspan.appendChild(text)

div.appendChild(textspan);

// edit <span> content
document.getElementById("text" + this.index).innerHtml = 'hello';


console.log(document.getElementById("text" + this.index).innerHtml);
console.log(document.getElementById("text" + this.index));
```

result

```
> hello
> <span id=​"text0">​Some content I want to replace ​</span>​
```

InnerHtml changes correctly but the browser (and the console) still display the wrong content. Why is that?

Comment: what is the value of `this.index`. first check it.

Comment: the value is correct, otherwise it wouldn't get in the console. Problem is with innerHtml instead of innerHTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`.

Remember that in Javascript everything is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content by setting your string to `innerHTML` or `innerText` Element properties. It is obviously what property for which there

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use  jquery `$('#your_id').html('some kind of a text');`, but if js suits you then innerHTML or innerText is used, as mentioned in other answers.